Can not quite apply recursion using XQuery
This is my calculate expression function and calculateMinus function
declare function local:calculateExpression($expression) as xs:decimal {
    let $result :=
        if ($expression/uli:times) then
            fold-left($expression/uli:times/*/@value, 1, 
                function($acc, $val) { $acc * ($val) })
        else if ($expression/uli:plus) then
          sum( for $child in $expression/uli:plus/@value
            return local:calculateExpression($child))
        else if ($expression/uli:minus) then
            local:calculateMinus($expression/uli:minus)
        else if ($expression/uli:int) then
            xs:decimal($expression/uli:int/@value)
        else if ($expression/uli:dec) then
            xs:decimal($expression/uli:dec/@value)
        else if ($expression instance of xs:decimal) then
            xs:decimal($expression/uli:int/@value)

        else
            0 (: Default value if no recognized operation is found :)
    return
        if (empty($result)) then 0 else $result
};

declare function local:calculateMinus($minus as element()) as xs:decimal {
    let $operands := $minus/*
    return 
        if (count($operands) = 2) then
            local:calculateExpression($operands[1]) - local:calculateExpression($operands[2])
        else
            local:calculateExpression($operands[1]) - sum(for $op in $operands[position() > 1] return local:calculateExpression($op))
};

Unfortunately it is evaluating the expression given below to be 0
                    <answer-debug>
                        <questionID QuestionID="Q4"></questionID>
                        <answerValue>Not Answered</answerValue>
                        <correctValue>0</correctValue>
                        <answerType>string</answerType>
                        <correctValueType>decimal</correctValueType>
                        <comparisonResult>Not Answered</comparisonResult>
                        <marks>0</marks>
                    </answer-debug>

I think I am applying recursion correctly here. Is there something I am missing?
For your reference, the structure of the question xml is
       <Question id="Q4" level="1">
            <Expression>
                <description/>
                <plus>
                    <int value="1"/>
                    <int value="1"/>
                </plus>
            </Expression>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="t">Well done!</Feedback>
            <Feedback answerCorrect="f">Please pay more attention next time.</Feedback>
        </Question>



Hard to know with only one small example to reveal your XML structure, but
$expression/uli:plus/@value

is clearly wrong because the uni:plus element does not have an @value attribute.
And when you write
for $child in $expression/uli:plus/@value
            return local:calculateExpression($child)

it doesn't look as if the calculateExpression function is designed to process attribute nodes.

I see, so I should iterate over $expression/uli:plus/*?

Also, you can find all the files at https://transfer.zip/#CnOZ_Oy7zAhMVgg8JAAJmFB2Fsp_h82VxSqVTlECsjI,f1773670-b7cf-44eb-b25d-1cb67afa2c1a,R

I haven't done XQuery before, so I am a bit lost. When you say that calculate Expression does not look like it is designed to handle attribute nodes, what do you mean exactly?

All the branches of your conditional use expressions like $expression/uli:times that only make sense if $expression is an element node, so calling the function with an attribute node looks like an error. I would encourage you to declare the types of your function parameters (e.g. $expression as element()) to get better diagnostics.

Here:
        else if ($expression/uli:plus) then
          sum( for $child in $expression/uli:plus/@value
            return local:calculateExpression($child))

you pass the nonexistent uli:plus/@value attribute to function local:calculateExpression($expression), and the function seems to expect an XML element.
So the recursive call returns the default answer 0.
